# Excel(VBA): How can I make my Comboboxes independent to allow user determined combinations to search database?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a userform with 7 comboboxes that  allows the user to search for data using some criterion which they may choose. My code currently works only if the user makes a selection/input **on all 7** comboboxes but does not work if the user decides not to make a selection in one of the comboboxes. How can I improve my code such that the user may choose to make combinations of the comboboxes  e.g 3 or 4 ans in any in order (maybe comboboxes 2,4,and 7 etc) and still get precise data?

```
for i=5 to totrows

If Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Project_code) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 5)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_TrueNOC) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_DNAmass) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Kit) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_QIndex) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Injection_time) And _
       Trim(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 10)) = Trim(User_search.Cbx_Instrument) Then
       Worksheets("Data").Rows(i).EntireRow.Select
       Selection.Copy
       Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Desktop\" & Wk_name & (".xlsx")
       Worksheets("Results").Activate
       Cells(1, 1).Activate
       totrows = Worksheets("Results").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       Workbooks("Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Results").Cells(totrows + 1, 1)
       Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Desktop\Data.xlsm"
       Worksheets("Data").Activate 
 end if

next i
```

Comment: Would you like to be used only the combo boxes having a value, or even if they have values, you need to exclude some of them? If this last variant, based on what rule to set the exclusions?

Comment: I'm hoping that in the event the user doesnot select a value/option; that combobox should be blank and be excluded as the code loops through the data for matching entries based on the combination of comboboxes selected. To clarify, each combobox looks for a matching entry in a column e.g 1st combox searches in column 2

Comment: This would mean using only of combo boxes having a value different then "" (nothing). Firstly, you must simplify the code allocating shorter variables (sh for `Worksheets("Data")`, cbPr instead of `User_search.Cbx_Project_code` etc.) and then condition the combo value to be used by their value.

Comment: Does your code, as it is, work? I was trying to prepare an answer, but it looks strange in terms of meaning... Do you want opening `Wk_name` workbook so many times your iterations are? Then, isn't `Worksheets("Data")` a sheet belonging to `Workbooks("Data.xlsm")`? This workbook is also open at each iteration. Can you better explain what do you want your code to accomplish?

Comment: Then, do you want considering an empty combo box like `True`? I mean, the condition involving such an empty combo box to be considered `True`? `totRows` variable looks to be calculated for "Data" sheet. Do you want copying the row matching all conditions in the same row of "Data" sheet, or in the next empty row of "Results" sheet?

Comment: Yes the current code works. So what I'm attempting to do is this; I have Data.xlsm or "source" workbook that contains the data. The user searches through the data using the search userform that contains 7 comboboxes (equivalent to 7 criterion that maybe used to search data) and each time the user does so, my code creates a new "destination" workbook that is saved as according to the user specification (Wk_name). The code loops through all entries in the data wrkbk that match the selection on the comboboxes and copy/paste the entire matching rows from source workbook to destination workbook.

Comment: My data has 12 columns and of the 12, my userform uses 7, represented by the 7 comboboxes e.g Cbx_Project_code searches col 2 and if the user only made this one choice, I expect my code to select all rows that match the selection made in the combox  in col 2 and paste them on the destination wrkbk. The code selects the entire row from col 1-12 based on that row's col 2 matching the selection on combox. I want all the other comboxes to be excluded at this time. Now if the user selects 3 comboxes, the code must select data based on 3 columns and exclude the 4, but now my code doesnt do that.

Comment: I asked you very clear questions, but you did not answer them... " Do you want opening `Wk_name` workbook so many times your iterations are?", " isn't `Worksheets("Data")` a sheet belonging to `Workbooks("Data.xlsm")`?", " This workbook is also open at each iteration.", "totRows variable looks to be calculated for "Data" sheet. Do you want copying the row matching all conditions in the same row of "Data" sheet, or in the next empty row of "Results" sheet?" Then, you use `Workbooks("Data.xlsm")` before opening it. I will not waste my time for something I cannot understand, sorry...

Comment: I donot intend to open it so many times. Its just that I didnt know how I could avoid that in my code. Also, worksheets("Data") is a sheet that belongs to workbooks("Data.xlsm"). I made a mistake when posting my question; totrows calculates the total rows used in worksheets("results") to find the next available row while lastrow  finds total rows in worksheets("Data"). I want to copy the row matching all conditions in the worksheets("Data")  and paste it in worksheets("results"). I do open workbooks("Data.xlsm") since it is where my userform is already. Also, I did not post the entire code

Comment: So, `workbooks("Data.xlsm")` is open and probably, it is the one keeping your existing code. Then the code makes some comparisons between form combo boxes and ranges in `Worksheets("Data")`, which belongs to the above workbook. According to the comparison result, it copies rows from "Data" sheet to "Results" sheet. Correct? If my understanding is correct, both workbooks should be open once, **before the iteration**, only their worksheets would be used for the processing part. Is it anything not true in the way I understood your need versus your code?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Both workbooks are open and up to this point, your understanding right. That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The code compares the combo boxes and the worksheets("Data"). If the row in worksheet("Data") matches what is in the combo boxes, the entire row is copied to worksheets("Results"). And is it possible to DM you?

Comment: Then, please test my code answer. About DM, you you mean sending a direct message? If yes, in which way...?

Comment: whatsapp or email can do

Comment: If strictly necessary, you can email me something, but usually I am busy and not check my mail for something else then my business... But, did you test my code and it did not work as you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. If my (last) understanding is correct, it should do what you want. It does not need any activating, selecting...

```
Sub selectiveQuery()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, totRows  As Long, totR  As Long, Wk_name As String, wb As Workbook, shR As Worksheet
  Dim cbPr As MSForms.ComboBox, cbTr As MSForms.ComboBox, cbDn As MSForms.ComboBox, cbK As MSForms.ComboBox
  Dim cbQ As MSForms.ComboBox, cbInj As MSForms.ComboBox, cbInstr As MSForms.ComboBox
   
  Set sh = Worksheets("Data")'Workbooks("Data.xlsm") must be activated...
  totRows = sh.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of "Data" sheet
  'combo boxes variable definition, in order to compact and make the code easy to be understood:
  Set cbPr = User_search.Cbx_Project_code: Set cbTr = User_search.Cbx_TrueNOC
  Set cbDn = User_search.Cbx_DNAmass: Set cbK = User_search.Cbx_Kit
  Set cbQ = User_search.Cbx_QIndex: Set cbInj = User_search.Cbx_Injection_time
  Set cbInstr = User_search.Cbx_Instrument
  
  Wk_name = "your workbook name" '!!!
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\" & Wk_name & ".xlsx")
  Set shR = wb.Worksheets("Results")
  
  For i = 5 To totRows
    If (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 2)) = Trim(cbPr.Value) Or cbPr.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 5)) = Trim(cbTr.Value) Or cbTr.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 6)) = Trim(cbDn.Value) Or cbDn.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 7)) = Trim(cbK.Value) Or cbK.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 8)) = Trim(cbQ.Value) Or cbQ.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 9)) = Trim(cbInj.Value) Or cbInj.Value = "") And _
            (Trim(sh.Cells(i, 10)) = Trim(cbInstr.Value) Or cbInj.Value = "") Then

       totR = shR.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
       sh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shR.Cells(totR + 1, 1)
  Next i
  sh.Activate
End Sub
```

It makes the condition `True` for the case of empty combo value, too...

The code is, of course, not tested. I do not have such files, I do not have such a form with necessary combo boxes. It is a piece of code which, theoretically should work. If some error would appear, please check if I correctly matched the involved combo with their real name...

Comment: @Magwaveni: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody spends some time to solve our problem and supply a working solution, thick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :)